# Last element in array syntax error?

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax-error

I need to fill an array and find out what the highest value is, which I've done. With this code:

```
full=($LASTOCT[*])
for i in $LASTOCT
do
    echo $i
done

echo "Highest value is: $(printf "%d\n" ${full[*]} | sort -n | tail -1) "
```

My question is that no matter what number is in the last element of the array, I always get this error: `./ipcheck: line 16: printf: 134[*]: invalid number`

Any ideas of what might be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
full=($LASTOCT[*])
```

to:

```
full=(${LASTOCT[*]})
```

Comment: (facepalm) Lol you know, when you stare at code long enough... Thanks!